# How to access web page using ip for laravel?

Tags: php, apache, laravel, xampp, vhosts

I am having problem to access my website using ip from a different pc. For example, the ip that I want to access is `192.168.0.150/season_pass`. If I use that ip, the page *could not be found* but if I just enter `192.168.0.150`, it can access the web page. Supposedly `192.168.0.150` should redirect to the dashboard page.

Below are the `https-vhosts.conf` file that I edit,

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\season_pass\public"
    ServerAdmin admin@localhost
    ServerName season_pass

    <Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\season_pass\public">
      AllowOverride All
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
      Require local
      Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The hosts file,

```
127.0.0.1       season_pass
::1             season_pass
```

For the apache, I am using `xampp` and the development is on `laravel` framework.

Comment: Do you have the .htaccess file in the public dir?

Comment: yap, I have the `.htaccess` file on the public dir

Comment: can u explain that "If I use that ip, the page could not be found but if I just enter 192.168.0.150, it can access the web page." ?

Comment: @YeLwinSoe if I enter the url like 192.168.0.150/season_pass, it can not access the web page but if I enter just 192.168.0.150, I am able to access the page.

Comment: do u have /season_pass route? /season_pass is not part of a ip or domain, it's a route or directory.